# expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'record_t' in header files c

Tags: c, makefile, header-files

I'm new to this header files in C.

What I'm trying to do is using makefile to compile my code files together. I have 2 header files and 2 c files for each header, also 1 main.c file.

I have main.c which is my main function and it has "#include "dict2.h"". dict1 and dict2 headers are somewhat the same. the difference is dict2 has additional linked list function.

```
-bash-4.1$ make dict1
gcc -Wall -c main.c -o main.o -g
In file included from main.c:6:
dict2.h:1: warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration
dict2.h:8: warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration
dict2.h:21: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'record_t'
dict2.h:24: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'record_t'
dict2.h:42: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
dict2.h:45: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
dict2.h:48: error: expected ')' before '*' token
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

my dict2.h funtion is looking like this:

```
typedef struct record_t;

typedef struct node_list node_list_t;

struct node_list;

typedef struct list_t;

typedef struct node node_t;

struct node;

node_t* transform_input(FILE *finput, node_t *root);

//line 21
node_t* bst_insert(node_t *root, record_t* data);

//line 24
node_t* bst_create_node(node_t* root, record_t* data);

node_t* bst_search(node_t* root, char* name_keyword, int* numcomparison);

void search_then_print(char* keyword, node_t* root, FILE* foutput, \
   int* numcomparison);

void freeTree(node_t *root);

void print_record(FILE* foutput, node_t* targetnode, char* keyword,\
  int* numcomparison);

//line 42
list_t *insert_at_foot(list_t *list, record_t *datarecord);

//line 45
list_t *create_empty_list(void);

//line 48
void free_list(list_t* list);
```

I've looked at the discussion online but and trying to fix it but I couldn't find the errors in the header file.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `typedef struct record_t;`? Aren't you missing something?

Comment: A few things about header files.  First you should have an include guard in every header file.  Secondly header files should only contain declarations of functions you wish to export and use in other modules. If `dict.c` is a module, it should only have `dict.h` of symbols it exports for use in eg. `main.c`.

Comment: oh I got the "typedef struct record_t;" at the top of dict2.h, I forgot to copy this into my question

Comment: Yes, and the compiler is complaining about that line. Take a look at the next line to see how your `typedef` should look like.

Comment: I've added the include guard for every header and the typedef struct record_t; but then I still got the errors

Answer (score 1):

Statements:

```
typedef struct record_t;
typedef struct list_t;
```

miss the typenames.

Should probably be:

```
typedef struct record record_t;
typedef struct list list_t;
```

Answer (score 1):

In the following, I use *struct tag* vs. *type identifier*. I googled a bit and found a (IMHO) quite easy to understand explanation on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_(C_programming_language)#Declaration).

---

Some programmer dude mentioned this but it seems you didn't understand his point. So, I elaborate this a little bit:

This is valid:

```
struct Node {
  struct Node *pNext;
};
```

and can be used with `struct`:

```
void insert_after(struct Node *pNode);
```

For whom which are to lazy to type the `struct` always a `typedef` can help:

```
struct Node {
  struct Node *pNext;
};
typedef struct Node Node;
```

It might look confusing but the compiler separates `struct` tags and types in separate lists. Thus, the first and second `Node` is no identifier "collision".

Both can be done in at once:

```
typedef struct Node {
    struct Node *pNext;
} Node;
```

Assuming another case without "recursive" usage of type, the `struct` tag can even be left out:

```
typedef struct {
  int year, month, day;
} Date;
```

This is a `struct` type which can be used exclusively without `struct` keyword.

I assume this was intended when writing

```
typedef struct record_t;
```

but the compiler interpretes it not as the writer might intend it. The compiler reads this as `struct` with tag `record_t` and a missing type identifier.

This is how I read the

```
warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration
```

(It helps to know that `typedef` is syntactically handled in the compiler like `static` and `extern` and, thus, counted as storage class though this seems not quite obviously to everybody.)

I must admit that I don't know how to interprete the

```
error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'record_t'
```

but I would ignore this and just fix the weakness in the `typedef` (and count the error as follow-up error.)

I also must admit that I have no idea how to solve this with an anonymous `struct` and go with the idea of a `struct` with a tag which is "re-used" as type identifier:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* typedef for an incomplete struct */
typedef struct Date Date;

/* use incomplete struct type for prototype of function */
void printDate(Date *pDate);

/* define the complete struct */
typedef struct Date {
  int year, month, day;
} Date;

/* implementation of function */
void printDate(Date *pDate)
{
  printf("%04d/%02d/%02d", pDate->year, pDate->month, pDate->day);
}

/* check this out */
int main(void)
{
  Date date = { 2018, 9, 3 };
  printDate(&date);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2018/09/03
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on ideone**](https://ideone.com/26dpRG)</kbd>